# How to dial a custom phone number using Phonegap in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phone-number

I'm writing an app using phonegap. I can open the native android dialer using: 
onclick="document.location='tel:0123456789'" . But i wish to open it with predefined number which i enter as an input. I'm receiving the desirable number as an text input like this:

```
function AddToScreen(a){
    document.getElementById('number_input').value+=a;
}
```

But i can't get the dialer to open with my input number.

How can i get it to work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the complete number you want to dial all you need to do is call:

```
document.location='tel:' + numberYouWantToDial;
```

Looks like you are most of the way there.

Comment: Yes, but after a get the complete number i can't get the dialer to open with it. It opens only if i use predetermined number. How should i attach it?